# How can we calculate percentile in druid while querying?

Tags: sql, druid

I'm trying to query 10th, 25th, 75th percentile for each row in druid from an integer  column **value**. I came across some solutions ( http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/datasketches-quantiles.html ) but not sure how they can be implemented. Can somebody explain it in simpler terms?

Comment: This needs to be implemented in the form of a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using druid SQL, it's pretty easy (once you load the extension).  Eg, you can use
SELECT APPROX_QUANTILE_DS(myNum, .25) FROM myData
to get the 25th percentile of myNum.  (If you search for 'approx_quantile_ds' on this [doc page](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html), there's also a link to a known issue.)

For native queries, I'm not sure offhand, but maybe this will help: https://www.druidforum.org/t/quantile-calculation/4929

Comment: What if we're trying to calculate it without using an external function i.e. manually using some formula?